# Print Json value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How do I print values of my fetched json object with each.

This is what i do

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
    console.log(key + ": " + value);
});
```

And this is what value contains.

```
Object
->Person: Array[1]
    -->0: Array[10]
         --->0: "id:8"
         --->1: "name:Holly"
    --->length: 1
    --->__proto__: Array[0]
->__proto__: Object
```

And this is what i get

```
0: [object Object]
1: [object Object]
2: ........
```

Comment: I can get the id by doing

    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        $.each(value, function(key, value){
            $.each(value, function(key, value){
                console.log(key + ": " + value[0]);
            });
        });
    });

But I dont think this is pretty...

Comment: Look at [Printing nested JSON without using variable names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110004/printing-nested-json-without-using-variable-names) question. In short, you need a recursion.

Comment: What do you mean by `print`?

Comment: Just take some good browser, no need to do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Either do

```
console.log(data)
```

or

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```

Comment: I want to be able to get the for exxample id to a string and put it into html

Answer (score -1):

Value is an object, so it prints like the object.

if you want the data in the object,

you will need to print each one separately as follows:

`Value[0][0]` ec..

Comment: I still have to do
console.log(key + ": " + value.Producer[0][1]);
When I use .id I get undefined

Comment: The id is in the array? First place? So Value [0][0] will give the id

Comment: Problem is that i will get strings like
name:Holly
name:Jonathan

So there is not a way to write the loop so that it can look like

value.Person[0]['name']

And this will be the utput
Holly
Jonathan

Comment: You want to print the name or the ID?

Comment: It does not matter wich one, but lets say i want the id
Then i have to do the loop, then I need to fetch the value and split it where : is and then I can do what i want with the value
Like
var id = value.Producer[0][0].split(':');

console.log(id), will output "8"

but is there a way to do this in a more simple way with the loop.

Comment: I do not think there is a way shorter, sorry.